# Comparing String Variables give different results

Tags: apex, string, debug

I was working on a POC and as a process of which I ran into a weird issue of comparing two strings differently gives different results. I might be missing something simple but wanted to see if there is really a difference. Following is the piece of code I'm executing anonymously.

```
string a = 'Cancel';
string b = 'Cancel';

system.debug(' sample test:'+ a == b);
system.debug(a == b);
```

I expected to get the same results since the comparison I'm doing is the same. The only difference is I'm using a debug identifier and not an identifier in the second log.

```
Results:
system.debug(' sample test:'+ a == b); -- false
system.debug(a == b); -- true
```

Am I missing anything here?

Comment: concatenation `+` has a higher priority than comparing `==`, First in concatenates `sample test:` + `Cancel`. Second, it checks it this concatenation equals `b`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think because it is concatenating `' sample test:'+ a` as a part of the left side evaluation of the `==` sign. If you do this:

```
string a = 'Cancel';
string b = 'Cancel';

system.debug(' sample test:'+ (a == b)); //notice parens to encapsulate evalutions of '=='
system.debug(a == b);
```

you will get this:

```
16:18:04.16 (16575910)|CODE_UNIT_STARTED|[EXTERNAL]|execute_anonymous_apex
16:18:04.16 (16921691)|USER_DEBUG|[4]|DEBUG| sample test:true
16:18:04.16 (16944462)|USER_DEBUG|[5]|DEBUG|true
16:18:04.16 (16998145)|CODE_UNIT_FINISHED|execute_anonymous_apex
16:18:04.16 (19048919)|EXECUTION_FINISHED
```

Comment: Another way to get around the concatenation would be to store the boolean in a separate variable, and pass the variable into the debug statements.

Comment: gotcha, thank you